# Select first by date of each group of unique key pairs in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :trainings, -> { distinct }, through: :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :training
end

class Training < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :user, -> { distinct },  through: :events
end

events table contains:

t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "training_id"
t.due      "date"
```

Imagine the events table has the following user_id, training_id and due date

```
[ 1, 1, 25/06/16]
[ 1, 1, 25/06/15]
[ 1, 1, 25/06/14]

[ 1, 2, 25/06/16]
[ 1, 2, 25/06/15]
[ 1, 2, 25/06/14]

[ 2, 1, 25/06/16]
[ 2, 1, 25/06/15]
[ 2, 1, 25/06/14]

[ 2, 2, 25/06/16]
[ 2, 2, 25/06/15]
[ 2, 2, 25/06/14]
```

I want to select the most recent value by due date of each of those "groups" (user & training key pairs).

i.e.

```
[ 1, 1, 25/06/16]
[ 1, 2, 25/06/16]
[ 2, 1, 25/06/16]
[ 2, 2, 25/06/16]
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Try `Event.order(due: :desc)`

Comment: That doesn't work I'm afraid - it returns all of them ordered by due date.`code` [ 1, 1, 25/06/16], [ 1, 2, 25/06/16], [ 2, 1, 25/06/16], [ 2, 2, 25/06/16], [ 1, 1, 25/06/15], [ 1, 2, 25/06/15] etc

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it using a custom query. Only slight problem is that it will select rows even when they aren't overdue as such, just the latest one. If I put in WHERE due < '#{Time.now}' it basically selects the one prior which isn't what I wanted but I can put something in the view to filter dates < Time.now as a compramise.

```
  @overdue = Event.find_by_sql("SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id, training_id)
         id, user_id, training_id, date, due FROM events 
  ORDER BY user_id, training_id, due DESC")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to clean it up a bit

```
Model
.select('DISTINCT ON (col_1, col_2) *')
.reorder(:col_1, :col_2, date_col: :desc)
```